# How to automatically recognize & move spam emails

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail, spam-prevention, email-filter

There are lots of spam emails in my inbox, but there are also several normal emails and other useful emails among them.

Is there any way to automatically recognize spam emails and move them to another folder while those normal emails remain in my inbox?

(Any email client that has the ability to achieve my purpose is okay.)

Comment: @KalamalkaKid he is using Microsoft Outlook, see the tags

Comment: @KalamalkaKid Thank you for your answer! I will be happy to achieve my purpose whatever the tool to use.

Comment: @ZhangWei youre welcome. Please accept my answer and upvote if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> By default, the Junk (Spam) Email Filter protection level is set to
> **No Automatic Filtering**. You can make the filter more aggressive so that it catches more junk messages. The higher you set the protection
> level, the greater the risk of some legitimate messages being
> identified as junk and moved to the Junk E-mail folder
>
> 1. Click Home > Delete group > Junk > Junk E-mail Options.
> 2. Choose the level of protection you want:

## **No Automatic Filtering**

> Although this turns off the automatic Junk Email Filter, messages are
> still evaluated by using the domain names and email addresses in your
> Blocked Senders List
>
> **Note**: *If you want to turn off the Junk Email Filter, you must also remove names from the Junk Email Filter lists*.

## **Low**

> If you don't receive many junk messages, or want to filter only the
> messages that are the most obvious junk, select this option.

## **High**

> If you receive lots of junk messages, but don’t want to restrict
> messages from senders on your safe lists, select this option. We
> recommend you occasionally check the Junk E-mail folder to make sure
> that a message you wanted isn’t moved in error.

## **Safe Lists Only**

> This is the most restrictive option. Any message that isn't from
> someone on your Safe Senders List or isn't to a mailing list on your
> Safe Recipients List, is classified as junk.

Info from [Microsoft Website](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-level-of-protection-in-the-junk-email-filter-e89c12d8-9d61-4320-8c57-d982c8d52f6b)

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](https://superuser.com/help/referencing). You must block quote text that has been written by some else. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help). This is your second warning.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out based on Kalamalka Kid.

Firstly, the Outlook email client whose junk email options are indeed for new received email, not existed emails in the inbox. But I found a trick by sheer coincidence.

For third-party clients such as Outlook, after adding the email account, all the emails that have been in the email account (whichever folder) won't appear in the client instantly. They must undergo a procedure to come to the client from the server.

In Outlook, this procedure is executed by clicking 'Send/Receive' tab, 'Send/Receive all folders' button. If there hasn't be added any email account, this procedure will be automatically executed as soon as a new email account is added.

Each new synchronized email will be recognized if it is spam as the same treatment for new received emails. THAT'S THE KEY!

Unfortunately, the Junk Email Options in Outlook is set to 'No automatic Filtering' as default. Meanwhile, this option cannot be changed before new email account is added and as I said above, the synchronization starts as soon as new email account is added. That's to say we have to think of a method to change this option before emails are synchronized to the client. So the 'trick' above is to close Internet connection before clicking the last button 'Done' of the wizard to add a new email account, which prevents Outlook from synchronizing emails from the server. Only now the 'Done' button can be clicked.
[Close Internet connection before clicking 'Done'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVQR7.png)

Then change the Junk Email Options to what you prefer and open Internet connection. All new synchronized emails will be moved into Junk Email folder if they are spam. (If not, click 'Send/Receive all folders' button in 'Send/Receive' tab)